# Laravel 5.8 show data of the another table like join

Tags: html, laravel, vue.js, eloquent, vue-component

I need how to show data in another table like MySQL join or something like that

## MySQL example

[image]

## My Code

Model usuarios

```
class Usuario extends Model {
    protected $table = 'usuarios';
    protected $primaryKey = 'idusuarios';
    protected $filliable = [
        'cedula', 'nombre', 'tele1', 'tele2', 'correo', 'direccion',
        'user_name', 'user_pass', 'fecha_ingreso', 'usu_idrol'
    ];

    public function Usuario() {
        return $this->hasOne('app\Roles','idrole','usu_idrol','desc_rol');
    }

    const CREATED_AT = NULL;
    const UPDATED_AT = NULL;
}
```

Model Roles

```
class Roles extends Model {
    protected $table ='roles';
    protected $primarykey  = 'idrole';
    protected $filliable = ['desc_rol'];

    public function Roles() {
        return $this->belongsTo('app\Usuario', 'usu_idrol', 'idrole');
    }
}
```

Controller usuarios

```
public function index(Request $request) {
    if (!$request->ajax()) return redirect('/');
    $usuarios = Usuario::all();
    return $usuarios;
}
```

View usuarios

[image]

that's what I need

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the controller that is returning data to your vue instance

```
//get all the users from the database (in your controller)
//you need to create a new array so as to easily map the role in the returned results
return Usuario::with('Usuario')->get()->map(function($role) {
            return [
                'field1' => $role->field1,
                'field2' => $role->field2,
                'field3' => $role->field3,
                'field4' => $role->field4,
                'field5' => $role->field5,
                'rol' => $role->Usuario->desc_role
            ];
        });
```